# How can I add custom HTML code to the beginning and end of the body element with tex4ht?

Tags: tex4ht, html

I need to convert a Latex document to several HTML files. I'm using tex4ht for this.
What I need next is to add some features to the web pages.
I managed to add the needed extra elements in the head section by writing a `.cfg` file and adding lines like the following one.

```
\Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{<meta charset="utf-8" />\Hnewline}}
```

Now I need to add the HTML code right after `<body>` and before `</body>` to wrap the content generated by tex4ht in some divs that the extra functionality to the web pages.
How can I do that? Where can I find good documentation about tex4ht usage?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two options for configuring `<body>` element, first one is `Configure{BODY}{start}{end}`, the second is `\Configure{@BODY}` and `\Configure{@/BODY}`. In your case it is better to use the second option, which is similar to `\Configure{@HEAD}`, because you can use it several times to add stuff after and before `<body>`.:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}

\Configure{@BODY}{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{<article class="main">}}
\Configure{@/BODY}{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{</article>}}
\begin{document}

\EndPreamble
```

this configuration produces:

```xml
</head><body 
>
   <article class="main">
...
document body
...
</article> 
</body></html>
```

regarding documentation, besides documentation linked from [tex4ht website](https://www.tug.org/tex4ht/), you can also browse [literate sources of tex4ht](http://michal-h21.github.io/src4ht/), which are huge, most important are [tex4ht-info](http://michal-h21.github.io/src4ht/tex4ht-info.html), which contains some coments on particular configurations and [tex4ht-html4](http://michal-h21.github.io/src4ht/tex4ht-html4.html) with configurations used in conversion to HTML

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me! I'll see the links you gave here. Thanks again!